# How to set up automatic adding of a comment in redmine when the issue status changes to a specific one

Tags: ruby, hook, redmine

I'm using Redmine 3.4.6 and I need to make it add a comment when the issue status changes to a specific one. I found out that it can be realized by controller issues edit after save hook, but i couldn't find any good example how to write a controller hook. I'm a beginner in Ruby and coding, so i ask somebody to explain what i have to do to make it work.
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWt27.jpg)

My code:

```
module RedmineAutocomments
  module Hooks
    class RedmineAutocommentsHook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
      def controller_issues_edit_after_save(context={})
        issue = context[:issue]
        trackers = ["Tracker1", "Tracker2", "Tracker3"]
        if trackers.include? @issue.tracker
          if @issue.status == "Ready for handout"
            @comment = Comment.new
            @comment = 'Some comment need to be added'
            @news.comments << @comment
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything turned out to be not very difficult:

```
module RedmineAutocomments
  module Hooks
    class RedmineAutocommentsHook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
      def controller_issues_edit_after_save(context={})
        @issue = context[:issue]
        case @issue.project.id
        when 9
          case @issue.tracker.id
          when 13, 14, 20
            case @issue.status.id
            when 26
              @issue.notes = MESSAGE
              @issue.save
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```